# Object array is not align with the grouping plane

Tags: modifiers, instances

I have created a grouping plane for array operations. Once I put the objects as the child of the grouping plan. The location of the chair moved to new location as in the screen cap. I can still do array operations with the grouping plane but it's not aligned on the grouping plane. May I know if there is any solution for this?
Many thanks.

Vinco

[image]

Here is the file: [array_question.blender](https://numeroasia-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/vinco_yiu_numero-suite_com/EXwBNF2iecdGigOqUDydhcIB1KRHvE8SaE5ubkUBW9x73g?e=ZGoPX1)

Comment: Hello, what do you call a grouping plane? Also maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I uploaed the file here : https://numeroasia-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/vinco_yiu_numero-suite_com/EXwBNF2iecdGigOqUDydhcIB1KRHvE8SaE5ubkUBW9x73g?e=ZGoPX1

Comment: Why are you making it so complicated? Why not joining all the pieces together (to make a chair object), then array the object? (no instancing, no parenting...)

Comment: Or join to make one unique object and instance it, no need for separate parts and parenting to an empty?

Comment: yes...your method work for me. Many thanks.